# Insert latest 3 records from a huge table(40 million records) which has data from different years

Tags: sql, insertion, dynamic-queries, incremental

I have data like below.. This is just a sample data gear wise but having more than 10 million records a year which we can insert into another table from this below table at a shot

```
Id name date
------------------
1  a    2018-01-01
2  b    2018-02-01
3  a    2018-6-01
4  a    2018-07-01
5  a    2018-10-01

6  a    2019-01-01
7  b    2019-02-01
8  a    2019-6-01
9  a    2019-07-01
10 a    2019-10-01
11 a    2020-01-01
12 b    2020-02-01
13 a    2020-6-01
14 a    2020-07-01
15 a    2020-10-01
```

Tried many approaches as data is huge and we need only 3 latest records from all these years; fetching from this large amount of data is not working using SQL queries.

Expected output:

```
Id  name date
----------------
15  a    2020-10-01
14  a    2020-07-01
13  a    2020-6-01

7   b    2019-02-01
2   b    2018-02-01
```

Comment: For **your** sake, tell us the database you use! **"SQL" differs a lot between database vendors** - so get an answer quickly, in the syntax that **you can use**, edit tags and choose one that represents your database e.g. MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle etc. (Do not go in reverse and choose more than one - that's just as bad.)

Comment: To format text tables just indent each row by 4 characters. There is an icon `{}` in the toolbar that does this as well. Refer to [site help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (in the footnote) for assistance on formatting.

Comment: Another reason to provide the actual database, especially in cases like this where properties of the table like indexing or partitioning could be impactful. Those will vary by database. Is this something that you are just trying to get working one time or are you going to have to run this regularly? What about ties if the id has multiple records on the latest day?

Answer (score 2):

This is a query that should run in recent versions of most SQL compliant databases.

```
select 
  Id
, name
, "date"
from (
    select 
      Id
    , name
    , "date"
    , row_number() over(partition by name order by "date" DESC) as row_num
    from your_table
    ) d
where row_num <= 3
```

The `row_number()` function simply supplies a set of integers starting at 1, this occurs within each `partition` (here it will start at 1 for each name) and the specific row that is given 1 is determined by the `order by` (here we sort by descending dates so the most recent is 1, next is 2 and next is 3 etc.)

If `row_number()` isn't available then please tell use which database type and the version.

**nb** "date" is a reserved word in some implementations of SQL, so you may need to quote that column name to be safe.

Also note that no matter what because you want the "latest 3 rows" and "per name" you cannot avoid sorting through the ~40 million rows. If you need to do this regularly then an index to suit this query may ne worthwhile e.g.

CREATE INDEX idx_your_table_name_date ON your_table(name, "date" DESC);

However, you would need to test if it does actually help or not, or, if the index slows down inserts too much.